# concurrent display of BMP file and text on Arduino TFT LCD screen

Tags: programming, lcd

I am using an Arduino TFT LCD screen (1.7'') on Arduino Due for displaying .bmp file of 80X60 pixels. Is it possible to display a .bmp image on the lcd screen and also display text/draw an object such as a rectangle, simultaneously in the extra free space available on the screen? 
The code I'm using is from the examples section in arduino IDE. File->Examples->TFT->Arduino->TFTBitmapLogo

Comment: Yes, after drawing the BMP, draw pixelwise over the TFTs framebuffer (without deleting any other pixels) or compute the whole framebuffer locally and transfer it one go. What library and display exactly are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I'm using the TFT LCD display 160X128 size by Arduino and TFT.h library. The .bmp file has to be retreived from the SD card. Could you please help me with an example of computing the framebuffer for text/object display?

Comment: I looked at the library and it already does direct writes to the TFT's framebuffer over SPI. So you should be able to just call `TFTScreen.text()` and draw over your bitmap after you called the `TFTScreen.image()`. function. Can you edit your question to include the current code you're running?